# Streaming Webcam Over LAN: HTML5 Video Element Not Loading

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, video-codecs

I am currently working on a project where I aim to stream my webcam over my LAN and read the stream in an HTML5 video element with minimal setup. My setup involves a server (192.168.0.1 dev/video0 -> ffmpeg) and a client (192.168.0.2 html5 browser). I am using ffmpeg with the codec set to h264.

Here is the ffmpeg command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0
  -an -c:v libx264 -b:v 1024k -video_size 800x600 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast
  -tune zerolatency -g 16 -keyint_min 16 -f mpegts pipe:1
```

This command is spawned by a simple Node.js server that shares this stream without any transformation (just pipe ffpmeg stream to each incoming connection).

When I use vlc or ffplay with the following command, it works very well:

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0 -framedrop http://192.168.0.1:3000/stream
```

I can even run multiple instances of ffplay and the video is properly played. However, when I try to use the HTML5  element like this:

```
<video src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/stream" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

The video seems to "load forever" without any error, nothing suspect in `chrome://media-internals`. I can see in the network tab that the network is reading the stream, but the video does not play (got same result using hljs and videojs).

[image: loading forever]

I am looking for help to understand:

- What is wrong with the `<video>` element in this context?
- Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Hard to say whats wrong. Try to open the video url in a seperate tab and see if it starts palying, or use other clients like vlc/mplayer/etc to see if there are any codec/transformation issues. `ffplay` plays *nearly* everything even if the data is massive corrupt or contains a bunch of errors. But your examples/commands looks good to me. So something in the node code? Please add the server code.

Comment: Hi @Marc, here is the nodejs code: https://gist.github.com/FranckFreiburger/1d3a6a98b92fa764f74608f7abc8d156

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Hey @Rob, I was talking to Marc isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your video is not playing because of the `-f mpegts` option. 
 This means (MPEG's) **TS** container format. This means that your `<video>` tag is receiving some bytes of `.ts` file data, instead of bytes of the usually expected `.mp4` file data.

**Possible Solution(s):**

**(1)** Use Safari browser to test your video tag setup since it has built-in decoding of TS container format.

*note:* If still failing to decode a TS file, then it means Safari expects an M3U8 playlist file (listing the URL of the stored TS file) which will not be possible in the case of piping bytes.

**(2)** If using `<video src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/stream">` then try this FFmpeg setup first:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0
  -an -c:v libx264 -b:v 1024k -video_size 800x600 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast
  -tune zerolatency -g 16 -keyint_min 16 -movflags frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov pipe:1
```

That will give you a fragmented MP4 container (as supported by all browsers) that you can play in the video tag like how your shown code is expecting to do...

Comment: thanks, your case (2) works well with `-f mp4`, but unfortunately, the stream has to be read from the beginning, when I try to read it on the fly (eg. after 5s) the stream cannot be read